# I have an error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

**Problem:**

I have an Image processing work and want to execute it in python notebook for multiple files. I have around 2000 input files (with Type 1, Type 2 and Type 3)

**The error i am getting:**

In my python code it is throwing an `Winerror2` . 
Can anyone help me how to solve this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
import cv2
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.tools as tls
from subprocess import check_output
print (check_output(["ls", "../Downloads/train"]).decode("utf8"))



 <ipython-input-12-3459aadc9e67> in <module>
  9 
 10 from subprocess import check_output
 ---> 11 print(check_output(["ls", "../Downloads/train"]).decode("utf8"))

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, 
*popenargs, **kwargs)
393 
394     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 395                **kwargs).stdout
396 
397 

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, 
timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
470         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
471 
--> 472     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
473         try:
474             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, 
bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, 
env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, 
start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
773                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
776         except:
777             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, 
executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, 
creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, 
unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
1176                                          env,
1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None 
else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
1179             finally:
1180                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
```

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file

Comment: Did you check the path where the file should exist?

Comment: Could you poste the complete error traceback using code formatting?

Comment: @mishsx Yes I did

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Sure I will do it.. Thank you for the reply